# Evaluating $\sum \sin(ak) x^k / k! $

Tags: summation

*Mathematica* tells me that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sin(ak) \frac{x^k}{k!} = e^{x \cos (a)} \sin (x \sin (a)). $$
How would I go about evaluating such a series by hand? My first thought is to expand $\sin(ak)$, obtaining
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (ak)^{2n+1} x^k}{k! (2 n+1)!} =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n a^{2n+1}}{(2 n+1)!} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k^{2n+1} x^k}{k!} =  e^x \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n a^{2n+1}}{(2 n+1)!} B_{2n+1}(x)$$
where $B_n(x)$ is a [Bell polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellPolynomial.html). However, it is unclear to me how to proceed from here.

Comment: As soon as there is a power and a $\sin(ak)$ think De Moivre's  formula.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sin(ak) \frac{x^k}{k!} 
= \Im \left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{iak} \frac{x^k}{k!}\right]\\
= \Im [e^{xe^{ia}}]
= e^{x \cos (a)} \sin (x \sin (a)). $$

Comment: Fantastic. I can't believe I didn't think of such a simple manipulation.